# get Contents of the child tag using simeplxml_load_string in php

Tags: php, xml, arrays

I have this XML

```
<parent>
<sms>
<response>
   <message>message</message>
   <reponse>text<response>
</response>
</sms>
<sms>
<response>
   <message>message</message>
   <reponse>text2<response>
</response>
</sms>
</parent>
```

I want to get the whole contents of response tag i.e `<reponse1>text<response1>` , `<reponse2>text<response2>` .which i will strore in an array. what i tried id

```
function xmlSplitUpResponseXML($xmlvalue)
{
    $returnSplit = array();
    $r = 0;
    if(simplexml_load_string($xmlvalue))
    {
        $xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlvalue);
        foreach($xml->children() as $child)
        {

        if(strtolower($child->getName())=='sms')
            {
            foreach ($child as $fields):
                if(strtolower($fields->getName())=='response')
                {
                    echo $fields;
                }
             }
    } }
 }
```

But the text is not echoed.
how can i do this.

Answer (score 0):

Your XML isn't completly correct, but when fixed - try this:

```
echo $fields->message."<br>";
echo $fields->response."<hr>";
```

Works on your given example, with this fixed xml:

```
$string = "<parent><sms><response><message>message</message><response>text</response></response></sms><sms><response><message>message</message><response>text2</response></response></sms></parent>";
```

Comment: Thanks I have pasted ( $fields->response ) these code inside
                if(strtolower($fields->getName())=='response')
But i am able get the 'text'. but i want this whole tag <response>text</response>

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, seems like you need some XPath to the rescue...

Given the following fixed-up XML (note nested response nodes)

```
<parent>
    <sms>
        <response>
             <message>message</message>
             <response>text</response>
        </response>
    </sms>
    <sms>
        <response>
            <message>message</message>
            <response>text2</response>
        </response>
    </sms>
</parent>
```

The following PHP will do it for you.

```
<?php
        $xml = simplexml_load_file( "sms.xml" );
        // Find the sms response (note responses are nested in a parent response for some reason
        $result = $xml->xpath('/parent/sms/response/response');
        while(list( , $node) = each($result)) {
            // to just output the value of the node
            // echo  $node; 

            // to wrap value in tags *bad idea*
            echo  $node->asXML(); 
        }
?>
```

Not sure why you'd want to return an XML string, seems like a bad idea to me.  What are you 
doing with the output?  Probably better to construct an XML document properly, just guessing...